# Lower bound for limit of length of codeword

Tags: information-theory

Here is the question I'm trying to solve.  I don't really have any idea how to approach it/what theorem to use.

For $ p, \lambda >0$,  let $m(n,p,\lambda)$  be  defined  to  be  the  least
$m$ such  that  for  any distribution on the space $\{0,1\}^n$
(of possible messages $\textbf X$) there exists an encoding function $c:\{0,1\}^n \to\{0,1\}^m$
and a decoding function $d:\{0,1\}^m \to\{0,1\}^n$,  which when used
with the binary symmetric channel with error probability $p$
give $\mathbb P(d(\textbf Y)=\textbf X) > 1-\lambda$.

Prove that $$\lim_{\lambda \to 0} \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{m(n,p,\lambda)}{n} \geq \frac{1}{1-h(p)}$$ where $h(p)$ is the binary entropy function.

Answer (score 0):

This is the capacity theorem for the binary symmetric channel, the reciprocal of the left hand side being the rate, and $C=1-h(\lambda)$ the capacity.